# What does the prefix GP or DE on parameter data types in a Python toolbox mean?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

What does GP and DE mean as seen on [parameter data types](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm).

Do they have an affect on what data is shown in the browse dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the prefix is documented anywhere. If I remember correctly:

- DE = data element
- GP = geoprocessing

They don't really mean anything to you, the tool developer. There is only ever 1 of each. There isn't a DEString and a GPString for you to choose from.

There is probably some history as to why there is DE and GP, and a best guess would be something to do with arcgisscripting and arcobjects. But yeah, I dont know those details.

Comment: Okay that kinda makes sense. I am guessing DE is an actual resource to be used and GP is used for configuration. There is a DEType and GPType but I get what you mean.